# Difficulty understanding the statement of gauge theory

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory

In the introduction the authors state that the reason for presence of arbitrary functions of time in the general solution of E.O.M is a key property of the gauge theory.

> “In a gauge theory, one cannot expect that the equations of motion will determine all the dynamical variables for all times if the initial conditions are given because one can always change the reference frame in the future, say, while keeping the initial conditions fixed. A different time evolution will then stem from the same initial conditions. Thus, it is a key property of a gauge theory that the general solution of the equations of motion contains arbitrary functions of time.” (Henneaux & Teitelboim, p.3.)

I have a specific reasoning in mind but can someone go ahead and explain with some example so I can check and proceed.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Why there are arbitrary functions of time in the solutions, is the question